# Min-width in MSIE 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

What is the *definitive* way to mimic the CSS property min-width in Internet Explorer 6? Is it better not to try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
foo { min-width: 100px }      // for everyone
* html foo { width: 100px }   // just for IE
```

(or serve a separate stylesheet to IE using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html))

Comment: This does not provide a min width in IE.  You are effectively just giving up on IE...

Comment: Prestaul, IE6 treats width as min-width.

Comment: My understanding is that this will work in IE6, but not IE7: http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx

Comment: The same fix applied to min-height seems to work in both IE6 and IE7 for me!

Comment: min-* works in IE 8. Maybe you should post a new question detailing your specific problem.

Comment: Nice, but in some cases IE6 does treat `width` as `width` (and not `min-width`). This sometimes works for me, and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an expression (as suggested by HBoss), but if you are worried about performance then the best way to do this is to add a shim inside the element you want to apply a min-width to.

```
<div id="container">
  The "shim" div will hold the container div open to at least 500px!
  You should be able to put it anywhere in the container div.
  <div class="shim">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

#container .shim {
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

This requires a little non-semantic markup but is a truly cross-browser solution and doesn't require the overhead of using an expression.

Comment: Typo: The entiety is &nbsp; standing for non-breaking-space in your code you had &nsbp;

Comment: Good catch! Two and a half years after this was published!

Comment: [lex parsimoniae](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1042&bih=585&source=hp&q=lex+parsimoniae&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a8459101ee7667e0).

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/minwidth.html) on CSS Play, by Stu Nicholls, shows the different methods for achieving min-width in IE, in all modes (Quirks, etc) and even for IE/Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I've fiddled with every answer given here in the past month. And after playing with Pretaul's method ([Min-width in MSIE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93274/min-width-in-msie-6#93530)), it seems to be the best alternative to min-width. No hacks or anything, just straight up compliant CSS code which takes 30 seconds to implement.

From Googling around, expressions seem to be the most popular. For me anyways, ittended to randomly lock up my browser (both IE and FF).

Answer (score 2):

I dunno, I had some success with:

```
    min-width: 193px;
    width:auto !important; 
    _width: 193px;  /* IE6 hack */
```

A combination of dustin diaz' min-height fast hack & [How do I specify in HTML or CSS the absolute minimum width of a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658/how-do-i-specify-in-html-or-css-the-absolute-minimum-width-of-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 0):

do your css tag as _Width: 500px or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well...

```
div.container {
    min-width: 760px; 
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 760? "760px": "auto" ); 
}
```

Comment: That CSS will not validate to W3C standards. Plus it can cause undesired effects [http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200611/ie_expressions_ignore_css_media_types]. Also, CSS should only have presentation, not behaviour.

Comment: Who cares if it will validate or not, this stuff can crash a users browser. It's very easy to end up in an infinite loop situation, since expressions are evaluated on virtually all events, such as reflow events, and the expression itself also causes a reflow. If extreme care is not taken, the reflow event can bubble back to the element the expression is bound to.

Comment: Yep, this code has real potential for disaster. It needs to check whether the width is less than seven-hundred sixty-**one** instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Min-height fast hack](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/) works for me (also works for width)

Answer (score 0):

The shim example is fine for forcing the browser to show a horizontal scroll bar when the container gets to a certain size but you'll notice that the content in the container will still be resized as the window gets smaller. I imagine that this is not the overall goal when trying to achieve minimum width in IE 6.

[Incomplete min-width technique http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/260264acec99b5aba3e77c1c4cdc54e94g.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/260264acec99b5aba3e77c1c4cdc54e94g.jpg)

Furthermore, the use of expressions and other crazy CSS hacks just isn't good practice. They are unsafe and unclean. This [article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/keep_css_simple/) explains the caveats of CSS hacks and why they should be avoided altogether.

I personally consider scaryjeff's post to be the best advice for achieving true min-width in IE6 and as an experienced CSS layout developer I've yet to find a better solution that is as applicable to problems of this kind.

> This [article](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/minwidth.html) on CSS Play, by Stu Nicholls, shows the different methods for achieving min-width in IE, in all modes (Quirks, etc) and even for IE/Mac.

I've provided an answer to a similar question that details the use of this technique to correctly achieve min-width. It can be viewed here:

[CSS: Two 50% fluid columns not respecting min width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191429/css-two-50-fluid-columns-not-respecting-min-width#230152)

The technique is simple, valid CSS that can be used in almost any situation. Applied to the shim example above it results in what I consider to be correct min-width functionality.

[Correct min-width technique http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/a67b2820bfbd6a5b588bea23c4c0462f4g.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/a67b2820bfbd6a5b588bea23c4c0462f4g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Single line button

```
button{
background-color:#069;
float:left;
min-width:200px;
width:auto !important;
width:200px;
white-space: nowrap}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use conditional comments to reference and MSIE 6 specific style sheet, then create CSS as below.

Compliant browsers will use:

```
min-width: 660px;
```

Then MSIE 6 will use:

```
width: expression((document.body.clientWidth < 659)? "660px" : "auto");
```

Comment: See Hugoware's answer as to why expressions that do this are bad.