# How to make IE respect max AND min-width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make IE support min-width / max-width CSS properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968779/how-to-make-ie-support-min-width-max-width-css-properties)

I have a site that has it's main navigation in a list (floated left).

The li elements need to have a min AND max width.
This css of course works fine in all good browsers.
But IE (9) doesn't react to it.

```
    ul.dropdown li {
            line-height: normal;
                    text-align: center;
            max-width: 145px;
            min-width: 88px;
            min-height: 30px;
        }
```

If I use this code on one condition, for example max width IE respects it.
http://perishablepress.com/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

But of course I can't use the same for min-width.

I need a solution that IE respects max AND min width.

Is there a solution?

Thank You!

---

edit: I forgot to mention i already added

`<!DOCTYPE html`>

;)

Comment: No it ain't because i already added the doctype and ie doesn't respect it, because if I use one condition (i.e. max-width) the min width is not respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
It wasn`t in the code, my IE just automatically switched into Quirks mode.
Changed it by going in the console (F12) and changed the Document Mode to IE9!

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it's work on my ie8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>template</title>
<style type="text/css">
 #content{
   height:400px;
   background:yellow;
   *width: expression(if(document.body.clientWidth < 534){"533px";}else if(document.body.clientWidth > 776){"777px";}else{ "auto"; }); /* set min-width for IE */
   background: red;
 }

</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to write this with ? and :.

Hack width with this : http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: That doen't do the trick, sorry. Same Problem, that IE just reatcs to one expression!

Comment: it's work for me, I had my xhtml code…

Comment: I used your code right here: http://tinyurl.com/ceaao4k as you might see, it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: To debug, you need to work on simplified version.