# html - td max-width in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I would like to limit width of columns in a table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
table tr td {border:1px solid; max-width:2em; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
</style>
<table>
    <tr><td>this is looooooooo ooooooooo ooooooooooooo ooooooooo ng text</td></tr>
</table>
```

The next code works well in Firefox (the cell has a limited width), but width is not limited in IE9.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968779/how-to-make-ie-support-min-width-max-width-css-properties

Comment: my code contains the suggested solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a div after the td like the following in HTML. Nothing within that `div` will stretch out the `table` cell.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/9S74F/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            this is looooooooo ooooooooo ooooooooooooo ooooooooo ng text
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

### Css:

```
table tr td {
    border:1px solid;
    max-width:2em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

div {
  width: 2em;
}
```

Works great in IE8, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The table is generated with jquery datatable -> I cannot put the content of cells into divs.

Comment: @user1977315 Do you need white-space: nowrap in your style?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use IE expressions `width: expression(document.body.clientWidth > 901 ? "900px" : "auto");`

Comment: I am searching for a cross-browser solution (if there is one..).