# CSS expression crashing the browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, css-expressions

In my website, I want the `body` tag to have a minimum width of 640px. Thing is, IE6 doesn't recognize `min-width`, so I'm trying to fix this with a CSS expression in my IE6 stylesheet:

```
body {
    width : expression(this.clientWidth < 639 ? "640px" : "auto");
}
```

But this is crashing the browser as son as I resize it. I've tried with `document.body.clientWidth` instead of `this.clientWidth` but it too crashes. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: IE6 supports CSS expressions? I have never heard of this. Is there a plugin involved you're not telling us about... or is this actually some amazing IE6 feature?

Comment: IE6 does support CSS expressions. I would avoid them. This S.O. answer may help you, John Doe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93274/min-width-in-msie-6

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tried many ways to do this but the only one which actually worked when I tried it was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93274/min-width-in-msie-6#93530). It's a bit HTML invasive, but it's a multibrowser fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `body` has `padding:0`, then this should work:

```
body {
    width : expression(this.clientWidth < 641 ? "640px" : "auto");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kt2m8/embedded/result/

---

In case there is some `padding` you could use something like this:

```
body {
    width : expression(this.clientWidth < 641+parseInt(document.body.currentStyle.paddingLeft,10)+parseInt(document.body.currentStyle.paddingRight,10) ? "640px" : "auto");
}
```

Demo with `padding:10px` and `margin:10px`: http://jsfiddle.net/vL689/embedded/result/

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work :/. I couldn't even see the example in jsfiddle using ie6, lol. Thanks for your answer anyways

Comment: @JohnDoe: I tried it in IE6 (6.00.2900.2180) with Security settings: Medium -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/HUBKx.jpg, i hope this helps.